# Mongoose - Find document's child array by a specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had spent hours trying to work out how to get records from a document's child array by a specific field, but I failed it.

I would like to pass a personId by a web service to find which meeting he/she has been invited to. As a result, I could track down whether the invitee has accept to join the meeting or not.

Basically, I have the following JSON output:

```
{
"status": "success",
"requestedAt": "2021-03-28T22:47:03+11:00",
"size": 1,
"meetings": [
    {
        "invitedMembers": [
            {
                "isJoined": false,
                "_id": "605ffbc00a21ed718c992549",
                "person": "a123",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

with a controller like this:

```
const memberId = "a123";

const meetings = await Meeting.find({
  'invitedMembers.member': memberId
}).populate('invitedMembers');
```

a meeting model class like below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const meetingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  invitedMembers: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'InvitedMembers'
    }
  ]
});

const Meeting = mongoose.model(
  'Meeting',
  meetingSchema
);

module.exports = Meeting;
```

and a invitedMembers class like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const invitedMembersSchmea = new mongoose.Schema({
  member: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Member',
    required: true
  },
  isJoined: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

const InvitedMembers = mongoose.model(
  'InvitedMembers',
  invitedMembersSchmea
);

module.exports = InvitedMembers;
```

The Member schema only contains a basic personal information such as first name, last name and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own problem by using a different approach where I changed my data structure by adding invitedMembers as an embedding model in the meeting model and updated the person field in the invitedMembers schema to _id.
Updated Meeting model class:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const invitedMembersSchmea = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  isJoined: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

const meetingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  invitedMembers: [
    {
      type: invitedMembersSchmea
    }
  ]
});

const Meeting = mongoose.model(
  'Meeting',
  meetingSchema
);

module.exports = Meeting;
```

As a result, I can find the invited member by ID using the following query:

```
const memberId = "a123";
const meetings = await Meeting.find({
  'invitedMembers._id': memberId
});
```